# app engine: incoming emails get rejected

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I'm trying to get a barebone app engine app to handle incoming email. I've followed the [Receiving Email](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail) tutorial, and my code is really minimal.

However, when I send an email to say whatever@myapplication.appspot.com, Google rejects it before it gets to my app:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
> whatever@myapplication.appspot.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain.

this is my app.yaml

```
application: myapplication
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+ 
  script: handle_incoming_email.py 

- url: /.*
  script: myapplication.app

inbound_services:
- mail
```

and handle_incoming_email.py is taken from the tutorial:

```
import logging, email
from google.appengine.ext import webapp 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
```

Any idea why emails are being rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you missed `login: admin` in the yaml file.

and it's `whatever@myapplication.appspotmail.com` not `whatever@myapplication.appspot.com`.

Comment: thanks! turns out I didn't pay attention to the fact that email email ends in .appspotmail.com. login:admin is not required, actully i removed it intentionally so that anyone can send in emails. additional note: I had forgotten an app handler so I also added this: app = webapp.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True) and changed in app.yaml handle_incoming_email.py to handle_incoming_mail.app - now it works like a charm!